# Oracle Query to delete all those records for which one column contains a specific string

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to oracle and I am using toad.

I want to delete all those records, one particular column(U_MSG) contains `", CALL HELPDESK"`

The column U_MSG is having 'bla bla foo abcd xyz lmn   ,CALL HELPDESK '

I Tried like this :

```
Delete * from mytable where U_MSG = '% ', CALL HELPDESK'
```

But not getting the resuls though. Any Ideas?

Also 2) How to delete that ,. I want to put space in place of ,.

I tried this one

```
UPDATE Mytable t
   SET column = REPLACE(t.U_MSG, ''%, CALL HELPDESK'', '% CALL HELPDESK')
```

Comment: This indicates design issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use * in the delete statement.  It will give you an invalid table name error.  And as D Stanley said, the like operator is what you want in order to use % as a catchall.

```
  delete from mytable
  where u_msg like '%, CALL HELPDESK';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LIKE` operator:

```
Delete * from mytable where U_MSG LIKE '%, CALL HELPDESK'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE 
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE U_MSG = ', CALL HELPDESK'
```